# how to get fixed number of strings from an NSmutable array in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i am getting 100 elements from xml and storing into an nsmutablearray.But every time i need to display only 10 elements how to get 10 out of 100?

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray *newArray = [oldArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 9)];
```

This should do the trick for you. You can create the range based on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new array adding only those 10 objects you wish to use / display.

Answer (score 1):

You can [slice your array](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/subarrayWithRange%3a):

```
 -[NSArray subarrayWithRange:]
```

E.g.:

```
NSArray* subArray = [myArray subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(10, 20)];
```

Answer (score 0):

while displaying put the condition like `for(int i=0;i<10;i++)`

and use this also

```
if(i>=10)
return;
```